# Identifying an alkyl bromide from NMR information

Tags: spectroscopy, halides, nmr-spectroscopy

This question appeared on an exam and I translate it into English.

> In the NMR $\ce{H^1}$ spectrum of a pure substance, with molecular formula $\ce{C4H8Br2}$, the following chemical shifts (in ppm) are observed: 1.95 (s), 3.95 (s): the proportion between the areas of integration of these signals is 3:1. This spectrum corresponds to the molecule: (A) 2,3-dibromobutane. (B) 1,2-dibromobutane. (C) 1,2-dibromomethylpropane. (D) 1,1-dibromomethylpropane. (E) 1,3-dibromomethylpropane.

Note that no access to chemical shift data or graphs etc was given. The answer provided is (C). I can see that 1,2-dibromomethylpropane has 6 equivalent hydrogens (in the methyl groups) and 2 equivalent ones in $\ce{-CH_2{}-}$ group, corresponding to a 3:1 ratio as in the question.

[Answer: 1,2-dibromomethylpropane [image: dibromomethylpropane]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhmzLm.png)

However, I cannot see why (A) cannot be an answer. It has a ratio of 6:2 equivalent hydrogens.

[Doubt: 2,3-dibromobutane [image: dibromobutane]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkwmLm.png)

I know I am not taking into account the chemical shifts. So I am not sure I could do that, therefore asking for help.

Comment: In it's present form, I would prefer 1,2-dibromo-2-methylpropane for the first structure shown over the currently used caption of 1,2-dibromomethylpropane.

Comment: Note that the names (C) 1,2-dibromomethylpropane, (D) 1,1-dibromomethylpropane, and (E) 1,3-dibromomethylpropane are all not valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a matter of [coupling distance](http://coupling%20distants) if singlet signals split into multiplets to be resolved as such in the NMR experiment. (Other factors, beyond your question, e.g., the difference between a C(sp³), or C(sp²), too.)

One of the general rules here, the greater the distance between to nuclei which *in principle* may couple with each other (i.e., a matter of their nuclear spin), the lesser the coupling, and the lesser the split of the signals.  So if you compare two cases

[image]

you count the number of bonds between the two types of hydrogen atoms in question.  Assuming coupling *by bonding*,* you have four bonds separating the hydrogens (case 1, where coupling is denoted as $^4\!J_\text{HH}$), or only three (case 2, $^3\!J_\text{HH}$).

For illustration, compare the 1H NMR spectra of ethyl acetate and propyl acetate. A $^3\!J_\text{HH} = 6...\pu{8 Hz}$ ([reference](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Map%3A_Organic_Chemistry_(Bruice)/14%3A_NMR_Spectroscopy/14.12%3A_Coupling_Constants_Identify_Coupled_Protons)), is resolved today routinely, which includes spectrometers of low magnetic field strength:

[image]

($\ce{^1H}$-NMR spectrum of EtOAc recorded in $\ce{CDCl3}$, $\pu{90 MHz}$; published by 1999-03-31 by [SDBS](https://sdbs.db.aist.go.jp/sdbs/cgi-bin/landingpage?sdbsno=889))

Now compare an analogue spectrum of *propyl* acetate, recorded in the same solvent and with the same field strength, where a $^4\!J_\text{HH}$ coupling occurs, with particular attention to the triplet around $\pu{1 ppm}$ about the terminal $\ce{-CH3}$ group:

[image]

($\ce{^1H}$ NMR spectrum of propyl acetate recorded in $\ce{CDCl3}$, $\pu{90 MHz}$, published by 1999-03-31 by [SDBS](https://sdbs.db.aist.go.jp/sdbs/cgi-bin/landingpage?sdbsno=4643))

While the lines of the triplet *at least* got broader, the split of the signal by $^3\!J_\text{HH}$ coupling is much stronger than the simultaneous one by $^4\!J_\text{HH}$ coupling.

*) A second mechanism is coupling *across space*, although molecular rotation causes this to be averaged to zero and thus not visible in solution-state NMR.